# Restore installed programs after windows installation

Tags: windows-7

My previous Windows7 was installed in partition C but I had many programs installed on partition D now I install new Windows on C and want to restore these programs.

How can I retrieve these programs on desktop and (control panel - programs) as newly installed ones ?

Comment: If they're not portable apps, and/or they don't 'just run', then you'll need to reinstall them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Apart from the program files installed on your disk drive, there are many changes made to the operating system and registry during an application's installation.

The worst thing you could do is try to "resurrect" a program by copying the contents of program files from an old installation in to a new installation. This will usually just cause problems when the program is reinstalled.

Each program needs to be reinstalled from it's original disc or setup files. If there is user data associated with the program, then the data will need to be recovered from a backup, or copied over from wherever the application saves user data. This is typically located in `%appdata%` or `%localappdata%` within your user profile.

User data should not, and probably will not, be saved in the "Program Files" folder and the contents within said folder are typically useless.

The exception to the above would be a "[Portable Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application)" designed to run without being "installed" on the computer. In this case, the contents of the program and user data are almost never located in the "Program Files" folder and are instead placed in a separate folder of the user's choice, and often times placed on a portable drive.

You should re-evaluate the practice of moving "Program Files" to a different drive, if not for for space saving reasons or performance reasons. This is not a method you can use to "recover" programs in the event you decide to reinstall the operating system.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [Ninite](https://ninite.com/). Great tool to rapidly reinstall commonly used programs.

Comment: @wysiwyg Yes, it is a great product I've been using for years to manage a large number of computers. But, because the question didn't state any specific programs, and I have a feeling this in regards to "commercial" products no longer available to the OP, I'm going to assume Ninite can't reinstall the products in question. :)